# Truncate Behavior in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load data in google bigquery table with OAuth authentication and Truncate mode.

Whenever I am pushing the data from mysql database table to google big query table, it is changing the structure of the bigquery table. Columns which are defined as REQUIRED are getting changed into NULLABLE.

Is this an expected behavior?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iPFg.png)

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: I am using WRITE_TRUNCATE.

Comment: You wrote, `it is changing the structure of the bigquery table.` What is `it`? Without providing a code sample, it's unclear what is actually determining the schema.

Comment: Hi Elliot, actually I am using Talend component to load data into BigQuery.

Comment: Code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1djXGWF6R4A3Zb2tpmzis1Bn3c0LKZQvB